# Getting count of like features types based on field attributes using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, cursor

I'm trying to create an update cursor which will take the count of the number of like features in a field and then use that number in a random number generator. The field would look something like that shown below:

```
**Field**
X
X
X
X
X
Y
Y
Y
Y
Y
Z
Z
```

As had been suggested by someone on here previously, I tried using collections however, I find that the result is not always accurate with the count total. For example I may have values greater than the total number of like features. I managed to get something working however, now I need something which constrains the random number without replacement and I feel the only way to do this is using collections. My code is shown below:

```
def sumdict(listvals):
    ddict = collections.defaultdict(int)    
    for val in listvals:
       ddict[val]+=1

    return ddict

dic = sumdict(row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(MyFC, (Field1)))

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(MyFC, (Field1, Field2)) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[1] = sample(1, dic[row[0]])
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Below is an example of what the output should look like, naturally the random numbers will vary.

```
Field1  Field2
X       2
X       3
X       1
X       5
X       4
Y       3
Y       5
Y       4
Y       2
Y       1
Z       2
Z       1
```

Comment: You are looking for something along the lines of X = 5, Y = 5, Z = 2?  How do you want to use the random number generator?  What would the output from that look like?

Comment: The output would have a random number to use x as an example between 1 and 5 appear 5 times in a different field. Field 2 would contain rows something like 2, 1, 3, 5, 4- all unique. Not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: I know the values will be random but I think a graphic of an example output that could result would make your question clearer.

Comment: I've edit my question to include a better example illustrating the desired outcome. I can get the random values in Field2 however, they are out of the range for what is contained in Field1.

Comment: OK so I figured out what it's not returning the results I want. Field1 contains many like values, more than I had realized when I had initially viewed the data, hence it's basing the calculation for total like values not just the groups I wanted i.e. there were other X, Y and Z values further down the list of records. I changed Field1 to another field and it works well if I use 'randint' in place of 'sample', which I think is due to needing a population sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take the following approach:

1. Generate a list of all of the letters and use a `Collections()` tool
   to produce a dictionary.

   ```
   for letter in [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ["Field1"])]:
       cnt[letter] += 1
   ```

   The `Counter()` will yield values in the following form:

   ```
   Counter({u'Y': 5, u'X': 5, u'Z': 2})
   ```
2. Start an UpdateCursor and loop over the paired keys and values e.g.
   (u'Y', 5)

   ```
   for c in cnt.items():
       ...
   ```
3. Set logic so that if `Field1` is equivalent to the key, write the
   random integer from 1 through (value) to `Field2`.

   ```
   if row[0] == c[0]:
       row[1] = random.randint(1, c[1])
   ```

---

```
import arcpy, collections, random

fc = r'C:\path\to\featureclass'
cnt = collections.Counter()
for letter in [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ["Field1"])]:
    cnt[letter] += 1

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["Field1", "Field2"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        for c in cnt.items():
            if row[0] == c[0]:
                row[1] = random.randint(1, c[1])
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```